# Unable to click dynamic elements

Tags: javascript

When *something* is clicked, it generates some divs (which I have called videos below). However, I cannot get my click event listener to work -- most likely because the videos/divs are being added dynamically.

The weird things if I console in the forEach, all the elements show up. So I know they are there. I am also not getting any console errors.

```
function openVideoPopup() {
  videos = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tv-video-and-copy'));

  videos.forEach(function(video) {
    video.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      alert('Test');
    });
  });
}
```

Videos/divs are created from PHP script:

```
$videos .= '
   <div data-id=' . $data['id'] . ' class="tv-video-and-copy dw-30 tw-45 mw-100' . $filter . '">
       <div class="tv-video-cont">
         <div class="tv-video">
             <img class="video-thumb" data-video="' . $data['youtube_src'] . '" data-src="../img/secret-tv/tv-' . $data['id'] . '.jpg">
         </div>
       </div>
      <p class="title">' . htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . '</p>
      <p>' . htmlspecialchars($data['description']) . '</p>
   </div>';
```

If any further code or explanation is needed, just let me know! :)

Comment: please provide code which generates these elements

Comment: what if you do in console `document.getElementsByClassName('tv-video-and-copy')[0].click()`? does the click event get fired?

Comment: Misunderstood your question. It says "undefined"...that gives me something to work with...

Comment: I think I am going to drop the .slice.call() and just try with a regular for loop. See what that does.

Comment: PHP runs on the server. Is that dynamic generation happening when the page is created, or at runtime, e.g. through AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add event handlers for dynamically added elements, you can add an event listener on `document` and then filter it to only fire for the related elements like

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if(event.target.classList.indexOf('tv-video-and-copy') > -1){
           alert("clicked")
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is my question on that though, wouldn't that really only work if I had one big script? I am working with small scripts (basically like modules). So I would have to do this in each script I need a click event right? But then that wouldn't work I don't think because only one event listener can be used per element or am I wrong?

Comment: Originally saw your idea here: https://gomakethings.com/why-event-delegation-is-a-better-way-to-listen-for-events-in-vanilla-js/ But ran into the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: You can consider making it another module and add this script file in the page you want ?
Or you can add this code in any main script file which is always included in the html file where you need click handlers

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is another route.

Comment: Great. Consider accepting the answer if this resolved your query :)

Comment: `classList` has a `contains` method that returns a boolean.

Comment: Yep, typically use contains here. Going to try to work this in if nothing else works. Thought there would be another answer though lol